# is this in 3NF?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-normalization, 3nf

**is this in 3NF?**

```
mysql show tables;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_hospital |
+--------------------+
| address            |
| bed                |
| department         |
| hospital_number    |
| phone_number       |
| region             |
| type               |
+--------------------+
```

```
mysql desc hospital_number;  //PRI key = Hospital_Number

+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name            | varchar(64) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Hospital_Number | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```
mysql desc address; //PRI key = Address, FOR key = Hospital_number

+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Address         | varchar(128) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Latitude        | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Longitude       | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Postcode        | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Hospital_Number | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```
mysql desc department; //PRI key = Hospital_number + Department, 
                        //FOR key = Hospital_number

+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Hospital_Number | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Department      | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```
mysql desc bed; //PRI key = Hospital_number + Bed, 
                 //FOR key = Hospital_number
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Hospital_Number | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Bed             | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```
mysql desc phone_number; //PRI key = Hospital_number + Phone_number, 
                          //FOR key = Hospital_number
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Hospital_Number | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Phone_Number    | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```
mysql desc region; //PRI key = Hospital_number + region, 
                    //FOR key = Hospital_number
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Hospital_Number | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Region          | varchar(12) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```
mysql desc type; //PRI key = Hospital_number + type, 
                  //FOR key = Hospital_number
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Hospital_Number | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Type            | varchar(12) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

*I made a database table using MySQL for the first time, and I don't know if this satisfies 3NF.
1 NF was satisfied by separating the department table from the hospital table.
I think 2 NF, 3 NF was satisfactory, but I'm not sure.
Please check my Databases
What is wrong part of my Tables?*

Comment: My only comment would concern tables `type` and `region`. I would think that there would be possibly a many-to-many relationship between hospitals and types and regions. If so, these tables would not have `Hospital_Number` as a foreign key, e.g. the `region` table would have the descriptive `Region` as before and as a primary key `Region_Number int(11)` and then there would be a `hospital_region` table with columns `Hospital_Number` and `Region_Number` forming a composite primary key. This table would allow the many-to-many relationship between hospitals and regions in a non-redundant fashion.

Comment: In other words, if you have a many-to-many situation now, you are forced to repeat the `Region` description over and over. Then if the region name changes, you have to change multiple rows. So, if multiple hospitals can be in the same region, you are not in third normal form. same goes for the `type` table.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) , So
`CREATE TABLE Region_Number(`
` -> region_number int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
` -> region varchar(16) NOT NULL,`
` -> PRIMARY KEY(region_number, region)` );`

Comment: `CREATE TABLE Region_Number(`
` -> hospital_number int(11) NOT NULL, `
` -> region_number int(4) NOT NULL,`
` -> PRIMARY KEY(hospital_number,region_number),`
` -> FOREIGN KEY(region_number) REFERENCES Region_number(region_number) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,`
` -> FOREIGN KEY(hospital_number) REFERENCES hospital_number(hospital_number) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,);`
is this all right?

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--you may find mistakes that make your question unnecessary & we don't know exactly what algorithm you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS This is missing basic info for determining NFs. PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: I could only respond to your comment with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I said about having a many-to-many relationship between hospitals and regions (or types) is an over complication: a given hospital is not likely to be associated with multiple regions (at least not in your model; hospitals *can* have multi-region presence). So we will go with your simpler one-to-many relationship. The problem in your model still exists whereby you may have multiple hospitals in the same region and if you decide to change the name of the region, you will be required to update multiple rows (same story with the `type` table):

Using tables `hospital_number` (which, by the way, I probably would have just named `hospital`) and `region` as an example (you can generalize this to table `type`):

```
CREATE TABLE `region` (
  `Region_Number` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Region` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Region_Number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `hospital_number` (
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `Hospital_Number` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Region_Number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Hospital_Number`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`Region_Number`) REFERENCES `region` (`Region_Number`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Note that in table `region`, column `Region` is not part of the primary key.